# what is sfParseException in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1

I have an error when I am trying to create a new project in symfony 1.x and php. If that matters I am on Windows 7. The error is displayed below, any thoughts??

> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
> [sfParseException]


 Configuration file  "C:\xampp\htdocs\sf_sandbox\config/../data/symfony/config/php.yml" specifies key "magic_quotes_runtime" which is not a php.ini directive.

[image]

Comment: Remove the line containing `magic_quotes_runtime` from `php.yml`. The Magic Quotes feature has been removed in PHP 5.4

Comment: Thank you very much. it works.although there is some problems.but now i know why that happened.